# Map with grid cells coloured in function of point density (R, ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I'm trying to create a map of Europe with grid cells coloured based on the number of records within a cell. Here I attach an image as illustrative of the desired output (see Fig 1 of https://doi.org/10.3897/phytokeys.74.9723).

[image]

In order to produce this image I have developed a minimal reproducible example with random points distributed across Europe. I have been able to produce a similar figure with levelplot but I'm particulary interested in doing this with ggplot as it will allow further customising. Is it possible to do produce a similar figure with ggplot? And if so, any advice of what path should I follow?

Note: The size of the grids/cells is irrelevant at the moment but I'll adjust it depending on point density. All of them have to be the same size as in the first example and they only will differ on the pattern of colour.

```
#Load libraries
library(rgdal) #v1.5-28
library(rgeos) #v.0.5-9
library(ggplot2) # 3.3.5
library(rworldmap) #plot worldmap v.1.3-6
library(dplyr) #v.1.0.7

#Create dataframe of coordinates that fall in Europe
coord <- data.frame(cbind(runif(1000,-15,45),runif(1000,30,75)))
colnames(coord) <- c("long","lat")

#Exlude ocean points following this post
URL <- "http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/110m/physical/ne_110m_ocean.zip"
fil <- basename(URL)
if (!file.exists(fil)) download.file(URL, fil)
fils <- unzip(fil)
oceans <- readOGR(grep("shp$", fils, value=TRUE), "ne_110m_ocean",
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE, verbose=FALSE)


europe_coord <- data.frame(long = coord$long,
                           lat = coord$lat)

coordinates(europe_coord) <- ~long+lat
proj4string(europe_coord) <- CRS(proj4string(oceans))

ocean_points <- over(europe_coord, oceans)

#Add ocean points to dataset
coord$ocean <- ocean_points$featurecla
#Exlude ocean points
europe_land <- coord %>% filter(is.na(ocean))

#Load worldmap
world <- map_data("world")
#Plot europe spatial data
ggplot() + geom_map(data = world, map = world,
                    aes(long, lat, map_id = region), color = "white", 
                    fill = "lightgray", size = 0.1) +
  geom_point(data = europe_land,aes(long, lat),
             alpha = 0.7, size = 0.05) + ylim(0,70) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-15, 45), ylim = c(30, 75), expand = FALSE)
```

Comment: This post https://r-graph-gallery.com/329-hexbin-map-for-distribution.html does specifically what I want with ggplot. The function of interest that I was looking for is geom_bin2d

Comment: There is also the `st_make_grid` function in the sf package.  This creates a polygon grid over another dataset which could then be joined to the points dataset and summarised.